# Google Maps API Implementing click event to get the target element

Tags: google-maps

Here's a question regarding Google maps API events:

```
marker.addListener('click', _.bind(function (e) {

}
```

In the above code I am unable to get e.target element on which I need to call a function.

Basically the situation is I have a list of markers and on click of one, the function needs to be triggered and on click of the same marker the function should unbind.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Also I need to enlarge the clicked marker.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so except copying one function ? Bring your code into context of your Question, format it properly! Show us your loop where you generate the markers.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I worked with marker in past and kinda had same issue, I did some research and found this solution on SO and it worked.

you can created function like this

```
function createCallback(marker, callback) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
     // do whatever you want to do
     callback()
    });
}
```

And after that call it like this

```
var markerPropertyLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {markerPosition},
    map : {map},
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            {iconImage},
            null, /* size is determined at runtime */
            null, /* origin is 0,0 */
            null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
            new google.maps.Size(20, 27))
});
createCallback(markerPropertyLocation, function(){
 // callback funcation
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we add a class specific to clicked marker inside the click event function ?

Comment: I am not sure if we can add class on marker, as far as i remember we can only add custom html for those marker's window. other than that we can change icon of marker. It doesn't provide many choices where we talk about css changes for markers. If you can provide little bit more details about what you want to achieve....?

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise with my requirements, I have restructured my queries and reposting the same:

On our Google maps implementation we have the following Requirements:

•   Getting the target element that is clicked marker, out of all displayed on the screen
•   Enlarge the marker once clicked and apply class only to that specific marker(clicked marker)

We have written the following code, but it doesn’t give the above results.
    However, a similar interaction works on hover showing the tootip with details

Code Snippet:

```
            ReferenceMap.prototype.showPoint = function showPoint(point, map) {
                var location = point.get('location')
                    , marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        store_id: point.get('internalid')
                        , icon: iconSrc
                        , map: map
                        , point: point
                        , title: point.get('internalid')
                    });

                allMarker.push(marker);
                marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude));
                marker.setVisible(true);

                marker.addListener('mouseover', _.bind(function () {
                    this.showInfoWindowOnClick(marker, map);
                }, this));
                marker.addListener('mouseout', _.bind(function () {
                    hideShowInfoWindow();
                }, this));


                marker.addListener('click', _.bind(function (e) {
                    // var markerTitle = marker.title;
                    // var markerID = marker.store_id;
                    // var target = markerTitle == markerID;
                    // if(target == e.target) {
                    //  $('.marker img').css('width',200);
                    //  dealerDetailsLeftBlock();
                    // }
                    // else {
                    //  $('.marker img').removeAttr('style');
                    // }

                    console.log(e.target);

                    areaMarkers.reset();
                    for (var i = 0; i < allMarker.length; i++) {
                        allMarker[i
                        ].isClicked = 'F';
                        allMarker[i
                        ].point.set('isClicked', 'F');
                        marker.set('isClicked', 'T');
                        if (map.getBounds().contains(allMarker[i
                        ].getPosition())) {
                            //console.log(allMarker[i]);
                            if (allMarker[i
                            ].isClicked == 'T') {

                                $('[title="' + marker.title + '"
                                ]').addClass('marker - design');
                                        console.log($('[title="' + marker.title + '"
                                ]'))
                                        // console.log(allMarker[i]);
                                        allMarker[i
                                        ].point.set('isClicked', 'T');
                            }
                            areaMarkers.add(allMarker[i
                            ].point);
                        }
                    };
                    //console.log(areaMarkers);
                    dealerDetailsLeftBlock();
                    this.trigger('getSideBar')
                }, this));
                if (this.markerCluster) {
                    this.markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
                }
                return marker;
            };
```